# How do I find cows in my survival mode Minecraft world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been trying to find cows in my world on Minecraft in survival mode and I can't find them anywhere. How do they spawn? Can I do anything to find them?

Answer (score 8):

Peaceful mobs have a *very* low chance to randomly spawn - you are much more likely to find cows with level/chunk generation. A couple things you may want to consider:

- **Keep exploring:** Almost all biomes can potentially spawn cows. Just keep looking, and you'll eventually find some. You can coax them back to your house using [wheat](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wheat), or guide them back using a [lead](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Lead).
- **Console commands:** If you're really desperate for cows, you can give yourself a couple cow spawn eggs. Throw them on the ground to instantly spawn a cow. To give yourself a couple eggs, type this into chat (cheats must be enabled):

  ```
  /give [PLAYERNAME] 383 2 92
  ```

Remember, you only need two cows in order to start a farm. Feeding two cows wheat allows them to spawn a baby cow, who will grow up into an adult cow after about 20 minutes.